# Switch to new window using Parasoft web test

Tags: parasoft

I'm new to parasoft. I want to switch to new window.
I see that there is a field in the browser playback tool named as "Window".
I'm assuming this is the place where window details can be given.
I'm not sure what value it accepts. e.g window title, or window url or count of window. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

there are two options: it can be a window number or window title.
If you recording web scenario with SOAtest, the tool should be aware about additional windows and gives list of all windows.
[image: Window1]
[image: Selection]

Comment: I guess Window number will appear only in case of recorded scenario. If  i manually construct a scenario and want to switch to another window then I guess the only option is window title using "custom" option. Pls confirm

Comment: Yes, you should use Custom option then. If you are creating scenario manually, you should provide window name.